# Changing an image source based on an H1 element in the source code or 'location.path'?

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I decided to try a different approach to this problem. Instead of relying on a string I thought it would be more efficient for this specific issue to use the function `location.path` to determine the source of the album-cover. Here's what I only have so far:

The piece of HTML for the image:

```
<img src="http://static.last.fm/flatness/catalogue/noimage/noalbum_g3.png" width="220" height="220" class="album-cover"/>
```

The piece of Javascript I have:

```
var albumCover = document.getElementsByClassName('album-cover') // Get the album cover
var currentLink = location.pathname
var dictionary = 
{ // location.pathname : image source for albumCover
'/music/King+Crimson/Red' : 'http://i1325.photobucket.com/albums/u622/last_fm_projeKct/Last%20FM%20covers/Red.jpg',
'/music/King+Crimson/Discipline' : 'http://i1325.photobucket.com/albums/u622/last_fm_projeKct/Last%20FM%20covers/Discipline.jpg'
}
```

Now here's the piece of the code that's incomplete:

```
if (currentLink === ''// first part of the dictionary)
{
    albumCover.src = '' second part of the dictionary
};

else{};
```

Any help is welcome and thanks for reading, cheers.

**Old Post:**
a follow-up on a question I asked recently but I can't seem to be able to change the code to match what I'm looking for. The code occurs on the following website: [link](http://www.last.fm/music/King+Crimson/Discipline)

I'm interested in changing the image source in the code below. However, the new image source is to be determined based on what the H1-element of that webpage contains.

```
<div class="g3 album-cover-wrapper album-cover-wrapper--no-cover " >
<img src="http://static.last.fm/flatness/catalogue/noimage/noalbum_g3.png" width="220" height="220" class="album-cover"/>
    <section class="r add-top-margin remove-bottom-margin">
    <div class="g4"> </div>
                    </section>
</div>
```

Now I thought it would be useful to use 'dictionary-list' like following:

```
if H1 contains the string 'Discipline'{img.src="newsource.jpg'};
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this, cheers!

Edit: here's a piece of code I tried but I'm guessing it needs more info for it to actually work.

```
var headerDef = document.getElementsByTagName('h1'),
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('album-cover');

if (headerDef === 'Red')
{
    img.src = "newsource.jpg";
};

else{};
```

A few examples of how the list will be:

```
//string in H1 : new image source for the 'album-cover'-class image
'Discipline' : 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41kcnkbxS-L._SL500_AA300_.jpg',
'Red' : 'http://img.noiset.com/images/album/king-crimson-red-4-cd-cover-31985.gif',
etc...
```

It's a list for which I'd have to manually add each instance of a page having a specific H1-string.

Comment: are you using any server side processing?

Comment: No, the idea is to create client-side Javascript to replace the images that are no longer available on those webpages.

Comment: Where's the `h1` element in your code? Is there only one `h1` for the whole page, or one `h1` per `.album-cover-wrapper`?

Comment: It's certainly doable to alter the image source based on the H1 content, but I'm not really sure what the problem is. Do you have a key/value list for every h1/image or are you trying to find an image on-the-fly?

Comment: There's only one h1 element for the whole page, also it's exactly the idea to have a list of a new image sources depending on the string that's found in the h1 at the top of the page. I'll add an example in the main post.

Comment: please try to answer this questions: 1- What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
var map = {
    'red': 'oh my gods!',
    'blue': 'blue? Really..?'
};

function influenceImage(source, map) {
    if (!source || !map) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var text = source.textContent || source.innerText;
        for (var word in map) {
            if (map.hasOwnProperty(word) && text.indexOf(word) !== -1) {
                return map[word];
            }
        }
    }
}

// in real life, with an image use:
// imageNode.src = influenceImage(document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0], map);
document.getElementById('test').title = influenceImage(document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0], map);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lf4Lp/).

In the demo I set the `title` attribute of an `a` element, but, of course, as noted in the comment simply set the `src` attribute of an image node.

The above changed, slightly (within the `else {...}`, to make it a case-insensitive search/match:

```
var text = (source.textContent || source.innerText).toLowerCase();
for (var word in map) {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(word) && text.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return map[word];
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lf4Lp/4/).

And another edit, again within the `else {...}`, in order to add a default option in case there's no word-match:

```
var text = (source.textContent || source.innerText).toLowerCase();
for (var word in map) {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(word) && text.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return map[word];
    }
}
// we only get here if the `for` loop and the `if` doesn't throw out a match.
return 'default string';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lf4Lp/3/).

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't seem to get me the result, I'll have a closer look and then come back with news. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the linked demo work? (I'm trying to work out if it's a browser/platform problem, or if it's a complication from existing-code...)

Comment: Yeah, the demo works just fine. The issue is indeed, having trouble handling already existing code. Cheers.